# Canvas creates copy of itself

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, html5-canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas that I'm trying to draw clouds on. It works fine when running in Chrome when testing in Ripple, and when running in the emulator, but fails when running on actual device (10" Samsung Galaxy Tab).

For testing purposes I commented out almost all code and just drew a colored rectangle on the entire canvas so I could see the borders of the canvas. I want to see one yellow rectangle near the upper-left corner of the screen with a bit of whitespace on the left (comes out to about 15px) and some whitespace below the header (total distance from the top of the rectangle to the top of the window is 42px). Call the upper left corner of the rectangle at position (15,42).

However, the tablet draws the rectangle but also draws a copy of itself starting at the very upper left corner of the screen -- position (0,0).  The 'correct' rectangle overlaps and appears on top of the 'bad' rectangle.

Here's an image of what I want it to look like.[image: What_I_Want]

Here's the HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="makeClouds">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#menu" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Menu</a>
        <h1>Make clouds</h1>
        <a href="#journal" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Journal</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="coverageButtons">
            <a href="#" id="decrease" data-role="button" onclick="decreaseCoverage();" data-inline="true">Less clouds</a>
            <a href="#" id="increase" data-role="button" onclick="increaseCoverage();" data-inline="true">More clouds</a>
            <p id="cloudCoverageDisplay"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="canvasDiv">
            <canvas id="canvasClouds">Sorry, your browser is not supported.</canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
$(document).delegate("#makeClouds", "pageshow", function() {
console.log("Loading page makeClouds.");
//drawClouds();

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasClouds');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 7;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();   
});
```

And here's the CSS:

```
#canvasDiv {
    z-index: 2;
}

#canvasClouds {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

I'm at a loss here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI, HTML canvas & android don't go along well. Lately, I've been bombarded with bugs related to the same. May be, you're suffering from the canvas duplication bug. check this issue  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474

Comment: thx for the link, will try the 'fixes' mentioned later tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set 'position: absolute' on the canvas (which is inside the div) and this fixed the issue.

Fixed from details in link from @AnupChaudhari.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35474